# To put image beside of dropdown menu results

Tags: php, html

I want to put image beside of my dropdown menu on my php code, but still not success.

The problem is all the  list of results is not under the dropdown menu.

This is my code

```html
<div class="col-sm-9">
<label>Duty Captain</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><img src="assets/images/icons/icons8-businessman-80.png" class="position-left" alt="" width="19" height=""></span>
<select name='dutycapID' data-placeholder="Select Duty Captain..." class="select-search">
<option></option>

<?php 
 while ($row_air=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cap1)){
    
$dcID = $row_air['pilotID'];
$dcName = $row_air['pilotName'];
$dcNC = $row_air['pilotNC'];
$fscrew1photo = $row_air['pilotPhoto'];
         
if($fscrew1photo!=NULL)
         
echo "<option>
<span><input type='image' img src='assets/images/users/$fscrew1photo' class='img-circle position-left' alt='' width='20' height=''> $dcNC - $dcName </span>
</option>";
         
else
          
echo "<option>
<span><input type='image' img src='assets/images/users/pilotnone.jpg' class='img-circle position-left' alt='' width='20' height=''> $dcNC - $dcName </span>
</option>";
         
?>
         
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

But the dropdown menu become like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zzoc.jpg

I want it become like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj1XR.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Does your console show any errors?

Comment: No error. But the dropdown menu show "no result found" as per this image; https://imgur.com/a/SplVT     the result displayed behind the dropdown.

Comment: Without using the downdown serach plugin, does your code successfully generates a selectbox with the options properly?

Comment: If I change the code like this <select name='dutycapID' data-placeholder="Select Duty Captain..." class="select-icons"> and echo "<option value='wordpress2' data-icon='wordpress2'>$dcNC - $dcName </option>";  the dropdown result can appear under the dropdown menu like this https://imgur.com/a/1L1NA   ....but iwant the wordpress icon to be displayed as a my staff image

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like following example

```
<option>
   <img src="your_con_image_file" width="10" /> $dcNC - $dcName
</option>
```

Alternative:
Or find out css based icons and put icons instead of images. For example if you are using Font Awesome Icons then your  should look like

```
<option>
   <i class="fa fa-list"></i> $dcNC - $dcName 
</option>
```

`fa fa-list` is just an example of an icon (fa icons)

Comment: If I change the code like this <select name='dutycapID' data-placeholder="Select Duty Captain..." class="select-icons"> and echo "<option value='wordpress2' data-icon='wordpress2'>$dcNC - $dcName </option>"; the dropdown result can appear under the dropdown menu like this https://imgur.com/a/1L1NA   but iwant the wordpress icon to be displayed as a my staff image

Comment: If I change like this : echo "<option><img src='assets/images/users/$fscrew1photo' width='10' />$dcNC - $dcName </option>";      the dropdown result will be like this https://imgur.com/a/ZwsQO   no image beside the result..